# How to make Sentences using Being?

Tags: grammar, sentence, subcontinental-english

Sentence - He is being in tension.

Above sentence is Present Continuos. How can we use Being in other sentences.

Comment: I cannot think of any context where *"He is being in tension."* would be a valid sentence.

Comment: @FumbleFingers.. k if it valid. than plz suggest me the use of being in sentences..

Comment: This question is Too Broad, as it would be if you asked us for a list of all the ways one can use, for example, ***having*** in English.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is better asked on ELL after improving/ making clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Being me, has its privileges". Dumbledore says this to potter in Half Blood Prince (film).

Use below link as well :

http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/being

It's all there on Google

Comment: very nice link.

Answer (score 1):

> I know what it is to be in need, and I know what it is to have plenty. I have learned the secret of **being** content in any and every situation, whether well fed or hungry, whether living in plenty or in want. (Philippians 4:11)

I think the OP wanted a gerund, but here's a noun, as well.

> We are not human **beings** having a spiritual experience. We are spiritual **beings** having a human experience. (Pierre Teilhard de Chardin)

Answer (score 1):

**Being** a Mancunian my grandson is a fanatical football follower. 
**Being** the son of a former Prime Minister, Nicky Blair, is able to make some success of his work as a football agent.
**Being** a born Scouser, Steve Gerrard, is proud to captain Liverpool.
**Being** regarded as a renegade Scouser, is not much fun for Wayne Rooney when he plays at Anfield or Goodison Park.

My entire state of **being**, is conditioned by my love of football.

Prince William, **being** second in line to the throne, takes his public duties seriously. He also takes a great interest in football.

Answer (score 1):

The present continuous of *be* (*is being* etc) exists, but it is rather unusual: it is normally used only when *be* has the special meaning of *playing a role*, so

> He is being the boss today

means that he is not actually the boss, but for some reason is in that role today.

*Is being* (etc) can also occur in a passive continuous: not very common, but perfectly colloquial:

> The car is being serviced today.

Others have given uses of *being* as a participle and a gerund.